# Proof theorem direct proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

>   For each theorem below, state whether or not the theorem is true and give either a
>   *direct proof*
>   ,
>   *proof by cases*
>   or
>   *counter example*
>   to support your view
>     **Theorem**
>     : For any sets $A$ and $B$ such that $A\subseteq B$ we have $\mathcal P(A)\subseteq \mathcal P(B)$

Here's my attempt:

$A=\{2,5,4\}\ B=\{1,2,4,5\}$ therefore $A⊆B$

$\mathcal P(B)=\{\{\},\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\},\{5\},\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{1,4\},\{1,5\},\{2,2\},\{2,3\},\{2,4\},\{2,5\},\{3,3\},\{3,4\},\{3,5\},\{4,4\},\{4,5\},\{5,5\}$
$\mathcal P(A)=\{\{\},\{2\},\{5\},\{4\},\{2,5\},\{2,4\},\{4,5\}\}$

So from my test I got direct proof

1. By assumption $A⊆$ know all elements of A are in set B
2. $\mathcal P(A)$ to be all subsets of $A$ and $\mathcal P(B)$ to be all subsets of $B$
3. by $\mathcal P(A) = \{1,2,5\}$ and $\mathcal P(B) = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$

All $A$ are in $B  = \{\{\},\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\},\{2,5\},\{2,4\},\{4,5\}\}$ are all included in $\mathcal P(B)$

also it's homework, so please don't provide straight answers; just indication : )

Comment: Please write in Latex and put your questions in text on  stack exchange. Using an external link, and even an image is completely unnecessary in this case.

Comment: You gave an example. An example is not a proof. A proof must show the truth of the statement in *all* cases — here, that would be for *all* sets $A, B$ such that $A \subseteq B$ — not just one case you selected.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $X \in \mathcal{P}(A)$ means by definition that $X \subset A$.

---

Full answer:

> If $X \in \mathcal{P}(A)$, then $X \subset A \subset B$, thus $X \subset B$, then $X \in \mathcal{P}(B)$.
>
>  Therefore $\mathcal{P}(A) \subset \mathcal{P}(B)$.

Answer (score 0):

$A\subseteq B \iff$for any $x\in A\rightarrow x\in B$

let $W$ be an element of the power set of $A$. Then that means for any $a\in W \rightarrow a\in A$.

is $a$ also in $B$??

would that mean $W$ is also in the power set of $B$?

would that mean $\mathcal{P}(A) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(B)$???

Comment: woops, had some typos, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Use the definition of $\subseteq$ and the fact that this is a transitive relationship.

Use:

1. $A\subseteq B \iff \forall x, x\in A\Rightarrow x\in B$,
2. $A\subseteq B\text{ and }B\subseteq C\iff A\subseteq C$,
3. $A\in\mathscr P(B)\iff A\subseteq B$.